# Wrong selection of a div containing a class

Tags: javascript, find

1. Look for a div that contains an 'a' element with an specific class (this step has been successful)
2. For that specific div (containing an 'a' element with an specific class), another class should be found for which a class will be removed. This step fails, because all div's containing the class filter-options-title will lose the 'closed' class.

   ```
   <script>
       require(["jquery"], function ($) {
               if ($("div.filter-optie").find('.shopby_link_selected')) {
                   $("div.filter-optie").find('.filter-options-title').removeClass('closed'); //this should only happen when the 'a' element with class shopby_link_selected has been found, which is not happening right now with this piece of code.
               }
       });
   </script>
   ```

Any ideas what I could implement in order to make it more robust, and make it achieve what I want?

Attached the HTML:

```
<div class="filter-optie">
    <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title closed">
        <label class="active" for="layered-filter-merk">BRAND</label>
    </dt>
    <dd class="filter-options-content">
        <ol class="items shopby_filter_items_attr_merk">
            <form data-shopby-filter="attr_merk" data-shopby-filter-request-var="merk">
            <li class="item" data-label="LABEL">
                <a class="shopby_filter_item_5cd9ce0ea7fbd shopby_link_selected" href="">
                <input name="shopby[brand][]" value="3989" type="radio" style="" checked="">
                <span class="label">XXXX</span>
                <span class="count">4<span class="filter-count-label">PRODUCTS</span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </form>
        </ol>
    </dd>
</div>
```

Comment: At the moment you are saying "is there a `.shopby_link_selected` class on my page?", "if there is, then remove all the `.closed` classes from all `.filter-options-title` elements inside `.filter-optie` elements" - The code inside your `if` statement, has no knowledge of the `.shopby_link_selected` code, you need to select it again here. Do you have your html that you can share, as this would help.

Comment: Hi Brett. I've attached the HTML that applies for 'a' elements containing the class shopby_link_selected

Comment: Okay, this makes things a little clearer, I'm guessing you only ever have one `.shopby_link_selected` class at a time

Comment: `if ($("div.filter-optie").find('.shopby_link_selected'))` will always succeed. If you want to know if it actually finds anything, use `if ($("div.filter-optie").find('.shopby_link_selected').length > 0)`

Answer (score 1):

@DigitalJedi, is almost correct, as this will remove the `.closed` class from all the places where there is a `.shopby_link_selected` but I believe that based on your html the DOM traversal is incorrect.

```
$("div.filter-optie .shopby_link_selected").each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.filter-optie).find('.filter-options-title').removeClass('closed');
});
```

This will find all the anchor tags with the class `.shopby_link_selected`, then for each of them, it will search back up the DOM for the parent `.filter-optie` and then back down the DOM for `.filter-options-title` and remove the `.closed` class.

Comment: Correct answer, but too complicated. You don't need the `.each` ;)

Comment: Correct, I was just building on the answer from DigitalJedi

Comment: Hi; your option seems good to what I'm looking for; however, I noticed that .shopby_link_selected has been added dynamically to the anchor tag, by which jquery does not seem to find it in the DOM (when I look at the source code, I cannot find the class .shopby_link_selected even when it has been added dynamically, so I think that's the reason why your provided solutions does not work yet; any ideas for that?)

Comment: I would need to know more about your code in order to help with this. The way you have written this javascript, it would just run at the beginning of your page load. You may have to include it after whatever is dynamically adding the class, or you may need an event that fires later. Wrapping you jQuery code in a document.ready() might help - https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 0):

You first have to find, all the elements that have a class `shopby_link_selected`,
then you have to remove the class only from those.

Right now the code in your if statement just removes closed from all elements with class `.filter-options-title`

```
$("div.filter-optie .shopby_link_selected").each(function() {
       $(this).find('.filter-options-title').removeClass('closed');
     });
```

EDIT: Sorry I havent seen the code snippet because i posted early.
as @Brett East suggests, his way will do the trick:

```
$("div.filter-optie .shopby_link_selected").each(function() {
  $(this).closest('.filter-optie).find('.filter-options-title').removeClass('closed');
});
```

Comment: This does not work. It tries to find elements with a `filter-options-title` _inside the anchor element_. By looking at the HTML the OP provided, there are no elements inside the `<a>`.

Comment: I didnt see the HTML at first it was an edit - sorry bout that

Answer (score 0):

You can use some "inverted" logic: Query the `<a>` elements with the `.shopby_link_selected` class, traverse *up* the DOM until you hit the `<div>` with class `filter-optie` and then find the element from which to remove the `closed` class.

```js
$('.shopby_link_selected').
  closest('.filter-optie').
  find('.filter-options-title').
  removeClass('closed');
```

```html
<div class="filter-optie">
    <dt role="heading" aria-level="3" class="filter-options-title closed">
        <label class="active" for="layered-filter-merk">BRAND</label>
    </dt>
    <dd class="filter-options-content">
        <ol class="items shopby_filter_items_attr_merk">
            <form data-shopby-filter="attr_merk" data-shopby-filter-request-var="merk">
            <li class="item" data-label="LABEL">
                <a class="shopby_filter_item_5cd9ce0ea7fbd shopby_link_selected" href="">
                <input name="shopby[brand][]" value="3989" type="radio" style="" checked="">
                <span class="label">XXXX</span>
                <span class="count">4<span class="filter-count-label">PRODUCTS</span></span>
                </a>
            </li>
            </form>
        </ol>
    </dd>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```